# Panorama image does not move

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a panorama application with a backgrond image if 800x1000 in size. I cannot make it to move when I browse the various pages in the application. Why is that? How can I make it move when I change the page?
This is how is set the image:

```
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/grass.1000x800.JPG" Stretch="None"/>
```

Comment: You should show more of your XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything to make it move or set the `Stretch` property. Just set the image to be the Background for the Panorama.

```
<controls:Panorama.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/grass.1000x800.JPG"/>
</controls:Panorama.Background>
```

Answer (score 0):

Panorama controls are on specific pages of Silverlight application don't move when you browse from page to page.  They should animate when browsing from panorama item to panorma item on a single page.